# Edit Post Permalink option removed, looking for possible causes

Tags: permalinks, filters, javascript

The edit post permalink button is totally removed ( not hidden with css ) from the edit view - but the slug is still editable from both the Quick Edit view and also via the "slug" panel which I can show from Screen Options.

I am looking for some hints ( wp filters or JS perhaps ) which will help me locate the code which is removing this feature.

Checking the other post types, I can edit permalinks normally on pages.

Things I have done:

- reset all user permissions, this made no difference.
- check how post types are [registered](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)
- Check [post type supports](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_type_supports/) calls for changes to the Post post type
- Looked at other CPT's I have registered, some which have the permalink disabled by returning false for rewrite ( but this totally removes the permalink feature )
- Checked as many other obvious places I can
- Checked ACF group settings in case any were set-up to hide permalinks

Things I will do, if no handy search hints help me locate the issue:

- Turn off plugins / themes one by one and try to locate the issue.

Edit Post view:

[image: edit post view]

Quick Edit view:

[image: Quick Edit]

Post edit slug meta box:

[image: Post Slug Meta Box]

Edit page view:

[image: Edit Page View]

CPT with rewrite => false:

[image: Edit CPT View with rewrite => false]

Permalink HTML:

[image: Permalink HTML]

Comment: Keep in mind  this isn't a discussion forum, answers will need to solve and answer your question fully, so you need to word your question in a way that lets people answer it factually and fully, in a way that all people with this problem will look at the answer and say "yes, that is the answer", not just what helped you most. To start with, disable all plugins and switch to the default theme to see if a particular plugin or your theme causes this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was an admin filter on **post_link** which was building a custom permalink and returning false in some edge-cases, which caused the edit button to be hidden.